# ASP.NET - How server side code is executed on user request from browser

Tags: asp.net, .net

In ASP.NET application, as far as I know the code behind is located in server and not in the browser. So for example I have a login screen and in the code behind, in the login button click, I am encrypting the user credentials before sending to the server. When the user is pressing login button, how the corresponding event is fired and how the user credentials is encrypted before sending to server?

Can anybody please explain me how the flow is?

Comment: [ASP.NET Application and Page Life Cycle](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73728/ASP-NET-Application-and-Page-Life-Cycle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are encrypting the credentials in the code-behind you are encrypting them on the server itself, they have not been encrypted on the client.  Whatever you have entered into the form fields in the browser are transmitted as the body of an POST from the client browser to the server.

If you are using the HTTP protocol, then the data you entered is clearly visible on the wire (you can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see this).

You'll want to use HTTPS which will encrypt the HTTP packet so that the contents can't be seen as clear text when the data is transferred to the server.  Whether or not you want to also explicitly encrypt the data on the server, before storing in a database for instance, is a separate operation and concern.

This [document from 4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20210411013534/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011404-1.aspx) is admittedly dated but hits the high points of how your request is processed.

Answer (score 0):

you will need [https](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) to do that, the browser will encrypt it before sending it to the server

Answer (score 0):

Since all the code written in the backend is exceuted on the server, your password encription is also done there. If you need to encrypt password before sending it to server, javascript is the only way to do it.  You can use javascript AES, DES, 3DES encryption algorithms. Here is a good example  http://point-at-infinity.org/jsaes/

Or you can use SSL to send your data to the server.

If you are intereseted in page life cycle events, here they are :

1) PreInit

2) Init

3) InitCOmplete

4) LoadViewState

5) LoadPostData

6) PreLoad

7) Load

8) LoadComplete

9) PreRender

10)PreRenderComplete

11)SaveStateComplete

12)UnLoad

Answer (score 0):

Please note that whatever code you have written for button click, it is on the server. So encryption will happen only when texts are received by the code on the server and not before that. I would not suggest encrypting those texts using javascript but you should think of introducing SSL. Running application in SSL will be a little bit slow as it has to encrypt/decrypt process. So you may plan to run you secured pages under HTTPS (SSL) and other pages under normal HTTP. Hope it works.